# Random laser modes its Q-factor(s)

Tags: optics, laser

Many papers about random lasers mention the Q-factor of random lasers. Since a random laser has multiple peaks close to each other like shown in the figure. Does each of these peaks correspond to a unique random lasing mode, or is it just a single mode?

[image: Randmom peaks during random lasing]

Similarly what is the right way to calculate the Q-factor of this random laser (example plot shown below) : Should it be wavelength at Peak1 divided by FWHM at (blue line) or wavelength of Peak1 divided by FWHM at (red line) ?

[image: Q-factor calculation in a random laser]

Should the Q-factor be calculated at -3db or FWHM?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t looked to see what the random laser practitioners do, but if it were me, I would fit the combined peak as the sum of two individual peaks and get the line widths from the fitting parameters. Then you just report what you did.